# How to trigger an OnClieck event for a ICON in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, onclick, icons

kindly help me out for this issue, Onclick event for the icon is not working!

HTML :

```html
<button id="create_project" runat="server" onclick="create_new_project" style="outline: none; border: none;"><i class='bx bxs-add'></i></button>
```

code behind:

```
protected void create_new_project(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        main_content.Visible = true;
        defualt_content.Visible = false;
    }
```

where main_content and default_content are two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you DO HAVE runat=server, then you can wire up the event this way:

In the markup type in onserverclick=

WHEN you hit the "=", you note intel-sense pops up this choice:

[image]

Choose create event, and now flip to code behind, you see a event stub like this:

Your markup will now become this:

```
<button id="create_project" runat="server"
 onserverclick="create_project_ServerClick"
style="outline: none; border: none;"><i class='bx bxs-add'></i>test</button>
```

And flipping to code behind, you see the event is created like this:

```
    protected void create_project_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```